# Terminology for neural networks

Tags: machine-learning, terminology

The words “a neural network” in machine learning can refer to either of

- The architectural design of a neural network (number of layers, etc)
- The network with specific parameter values encoded in it.

The first we can call “neural net architecture”, but how do we specifically refer to the second?

Answer (score 2):

I cannot leave a comment, that is why I leave an answer.

> The network with specific parameter values encoded in it.

A (trained) neural network model